# Command-line NHL skaters stats tool

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

Have been playing with the undocumented NHL API for some days. I'd love to see any input about this little script. About overall structure, style, performance enhancements, etc. Not sure how to properly use long links in Python, should I even follow the PEP in this case? The same problem in a couple of other lines, it exceeds 79 symbols limit. Not sure if I should use pluses in the 'printed_info' lines, it behaves the same way without it, but some say it's more explicit, so it's better.

```
import requests
import json
import os
import collections
import timeit
import datetime


def basic_bio():
    api_basic_bio = "http://www.nhl.com/stats/rest/skaters?isAggregate=false&reportType=basic&isGame=false&reportName=skaterpercentages&cayenneExp=gameTypeId=2%20and%20seasonId=20182019"

    json_data = requests.get(api_basic_bio).json()
    basic_full_bio_list = json_data["data"]
    return basic_full_bio_list


def lastnames():
    list_lastnames = []
    players_range = range(len(basic_bio()))
    json_bios = basic_bio()

    for number in players_range:
        list_lastnames.append((json_bios[number]["playerLastName"]).lower())

    return list_lastnames


def duplicate_last_names():
    last_names_count = collections.Counter(lastnames())
    dup_last_names = {k: v for k, v in last_names_count.items() if v > 1}
    return dup_last_names


def get_id_name_dict():
    players_id_dict = {}
    players_range = range(len(basic_bio()))
    dups = duplicate_last_names()
    skaters = basic_bio()

    for number in players_range:
        if (skaters[number]["playerLastName"]).lower() in dups:
            players_id_dict[skaters[number]["playerName"].lower()] = skaters[number]["playerId"]
        else:
            players_id_dict[skaters[number]["playerLastName"].lower()] = skaters[number]["playerId"]

    with open('nhl_skaters_id.json', 'w') as file:
         file.write(json.dumps(players_id_dict, indent=4, sort_keys=True))


def get_id(player_lastname):
    with open('nhl_skaters_id.json') as file:
      data = json.load(file)
    dups = duplicate_last_names()

    if player_lastname in dups:
        player_firstname = input("Enter a player's firstname: ").lower()
        return data[player_firstname + ' ' + player_lastname]
    else:
        return data[player_lastname]


def get_stats(id):
    api_base = 'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/'
    api_end = '?hydrate=stats(splits=statsSingleSeason)'
    url = ''.join([api_base, str(id), api_end])
    json_data = requests.get(url).json()
    stats = json_data["people"]
    return stats


def show_stats(data):
    path_stats = data[0]['stats'][0]['splits'][0]['stat']
    path_bio = data[0]

    printed_info = (f"Name: {path_bio['fullName']}\n\n" +
         f"Birth Date: {path_bio['birthDate']}\n" +
         f"Height: {path_bio['height']}\n" +
         f"Weight: {path_bio['weight']}\n\n" +
         f"Games: {path_stats['games']}\n" +
         f"Goals: {path_stats['goals']}\n" +
         f"Assists: {path_stats['assists']}\n" +
         f"Points: {path_stats['points']}\n" +
         f"PP Points: {path_stats['powerPlayPoints']}\n" +
         f"Plus-minus: {path_stats['plusMinus']}\n" +
         f"Shots: {path_stats['shots']}\n" +
         f"Hits: {path_stats['hits']}\n" +
         f"Blocks: {path_stats['blocked']}\n" +
         f"Penalty Minutes: {path_stats['pim']}\n" +
         f"TOI per Game: {path_stats['timeOnIcePerGame']}\n" +
         f"PP TOI per Game: {path_stats['powerPlayTimeOnIcePerGame']}\n" +
         f"SH TOI per Game: {path_stats['shortHandedTimeOnIcePerGame']}\n")

    print(printed_info)


def data_old(file_name):
    one_day_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    filetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file_name))

    if filetime < one_day_ago:
        return True
    else:
        return False


player_lastname = input("Enter a player's lastname: ").lower()

if os.path.isfile('nhl_skaters_id.json') == False or data_old('nhl_skaters_id.json') == True:
    get_id_name_dict()

try:
    data = get_stats(get_id(player_lastname))
    print('-----------------------------')
    show_stats(data)
except Exception:
    print(f"{player_lastname.capitalize()} did't play any NHL games this season")
```

Comment: Just figured out that I could capitalize() both user inputs and do not use lower() and capitalize() calls in any other place of the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- One way to deal with long URLs that are long because of lots of parameters is to let `requests` deal with those parameters by passing a dictionary:

  ```
  URL = "http://www.nhl.com/stats/rest/{}"

  def basic_bio():
      params = {"isAggregate": "false",
                "reportType": "basic",
                "isGame": "false",
                "reportName": "skaterpercentages",
                "cayenneExp": "gameTypeId=2 and seasonId=20182019"}
      return requests.get(URL.format("skaters"), params=params).json()["data"]
  ```

  It even performs the urlencoding for you (by escaping the spaces in the last parameter, in this case).
- [Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself). In addition, always try to [iterate over the elements of an iterable, instead of indices](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html). This allows you to use iterable but not indexable things (like generators). For `lastnames`, you can use a list comprehension, though:

  ```
  def lastnames():
      return [player["playerLastName"].lower() for player in basic_bio()]
  ```
- Python has multiline strings:

  ```
  PLAYER_STATS = """Name: {fullName}

  Birth Date: {birthDate}
  Height: {height}
  ...
  SH TOI per Game: {shortHandedTimeOnIcePerGame}

  """

  def show_stats(data):
      path_stats = data[0]['stats'][0]['splits'][0]['stat']
      path_bio = data[0]
      print(PLAYER_STATS.format(**path_bio, **path_stats))
  ```

  This uses the fact that in Python 3 you can keyword expand multiple mappings. It is OK if not all keys of the dictionary/ies are used.
- Instead of comparing something directly with `False` or `True`, like in

  ```
  if os.path.isfile('nhl_skaters_id.json') == False or data_old('nhl_skaters_id.json') == True:
      # get info
  ```

  just do

  ```
  skaters_json = 'nhl_skaters_id.json'
  if not os.path.isfile(skaters_json) or data_old(skaters_json):
      # get info
  ```
- Don't explicitly return `True` or `False` unless you really have to. Instead of

  ```
  if filetime < one_day_ago:
      return True
  else:
      return False
  ```

  Just do

  ```
  return filetime < one_day_ago
  ```
- You should wrap your calling code in a [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to allow importing from this script without executing those functions.
- When catching exceptions, try to be as specific as possible. `except Exception` is already better than a bare except (because at least it does not prevent the user from exiting using Ctrl+C), but if you know the specific exception (or exceptions) you want to guard against, then use that knowledge. Here it is probably a `IndexError` or `KeyError`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your review! Now going through it. Item by item. About the first one. That way with dictionary looking good. But why is there 'data=params', shouldn't it just be 'params'?

Comment: And about the return line in the method. Is it a pythonic way to chain three or more functions in one line? I've used to it when I've been learning Ruby, but it seemed to me that in Python it's not always the case. In a lot of code examples, I've seen it was done in a way that there is one function in one line. The same applies for 'Don't explicitly return True or False', I've never done this in Ruby.  Started to do this in Python. Maybe I've taken 'Explicit is better than implicit' way too seriously :)

Comment: @Flynn84 The `data=params` is setting a keyword explicitly. It might be that that is the right place when doing it positionally, but this way it is clearer.

Comment: @Flynn84 Chaining calls like this is indeed a balancing act between simplicity (no need for intermediate variables which are only used once and for which you need to find sensible names) and readability (Chaining too many calls will obfuscate what the object represents). In general I tend to chain them if the intermediate objects are used nowhere, the length of the line stays within 80 chars and the chain is relatively easy to follow (like here).

Comment: @Flynn84 This trade-off is actually why I did not say I recommend doing it that way, but just did it in the example I used so you can decide for yourself which one you like better.

Comment: @Flynn84 And the part about explicitly returning `True`, I agree here the common practice seems to disagree with the Python Zen. However, remember that there is also "Simple is better than complex." and "Flat is better than nested." In Python duck-typing is often used ("If it quacks like a duck...it's probably a duck"). This means that many methods return only truthy or falsy objects, instead of `True` and `False` and that is fine.

Comment: But I'm getting the 'Http Response 500' when using data=params.

Comment: @Flynn84: I fixed it. The `data` keyword is needed when posting data, `params` is what is needed here.

Comment: Yeah, I could've read docs more thoroughly, just read about the difference between params and data.

Comment: Btw, while we at it, a bit of offtopic. The only thing that I didn't like about Python in compare to Ruby is that I didn't like how the official docs are structured.  It is only me or this 1. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/  2. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html  is better structured than  3. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html#reference-index  4. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types   I caught myself using SO and other sources rather than official docs for a new info. I guess it's just a power of habit.

Comment: That show_stats method looking so clean now, so beautiful! Just trying to fully understand how this works. How the format know that {games} is correspond to path_stats['games']

Comment: @Flynn84: It knows it because both `path_bio` and `path_stats` are dictionaries that are keyword unpacked into the `format` call by the `**`. Therefore this boils down to `PLAYER_STATS.format(fullName=path_bio['fullName'], ..., shortHandedTimeOnIcePerGame=path_stats['shortHandedTimeOnIcePerGame']`. The only thing you need to be mindful of is that if a key exists in both dictionaries, this will raise a `TypeError`.

Comment: I'm trying to make the code more DRY. Rewrote the loop in the `get_id_name_dict()` method. And the thing is bugging me is that I couldn't understand why it didn't work like I thought it would. I mean, when trying to get rid of `dups` variable, why is taking so much more time when `if (skaters[number]["playerLastName"]).lower() in duplicate_last_names()` in compare with `if (player["playerLastName"]).lower() in dups`. I've had some assumptions, but couldn't confirm it playing with the code

Comment: @Flynn84: It takes so much more time because the `duplicate_last_names` function is called every loop iteration, instead of only once.